# How to config Ofbiz in production

Tags: ofbiz

As we know the default web URL for ofbiz is likely "https://localhost:8443/ecommerce/control/main". However when we move to production
we will only need to show "www.mydomain.com for the first page, how to config? if we use Tomcat we can config in server.xml, however we cannot find this file in Ofbiz since it integrated with tomcat, Please help, thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the settings at the domain server as well as OFBiz end.

Please refer this [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Apache+OFBiz+Technical+Production+Setup+Guide) for production related settings.

You can change the URL related properties in framework/webapp/config/url.properties

You can change the Tomcat server settings in framework/catalina/ofbiz-component.xml

You can also use Apache OFBiz user mailing [list](https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) for such queries.

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your advice, after setting 80 and 443 port in framework/webapp/config/url.properties & framework/catalina/ofbiz-component.xml, I successfully remove the port. and by setting  mount-point="/ecommerce" to specialpurpose/ecommerce/ofbiz-component.xml in specialpurpose/ecommerce/ofbiz-component.xml, finally I can get this https://localhost:8443/control/main. My question is how to remove control/main, thanks again.

Comment: You can change it in ecommerce/webapp/ecommerce/WEB-INF/web.xml file by changing ControlServlet and redirectPath values.

Comment: Can you kindly help how to change it, thanks.         
            <param-name>allowedPaths</param-name>
            <param-value>/error:/control:/products:/select:/index.html:/index.jsp:/robots.txt:/default.html:/default.jsp:/images</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>redirectPath</param-name>
            <param-value>/control/main</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControlServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/control/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Change ControlServlet value to /* and redirectPath to /main

Comment: Thanks a lots, I find another issue when i follow you direction, that's  the subpage(product detailed page) can not be open, it always direct to the main page, how to fix it, thanks again.